# Easily apply "bookend" deletion of AI-generated content

Tags: script, moderation

### Description

This is a fork of [Samuel Liew's DeletedUsersHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/DeletedUsersHelper.user.js) userscript. It's a script for moderators only.

The purpose of this userscript is to simplify bulk-deletion of AI-generated posts as per the [bookend policy](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/gen-ai-heuristics/questions/310).

### How it works

The script adds a button at the top of the user's Answers tab:

[image]

By clicking the button, a checkbox is appended to each entry in the answers list, as well as a Delete button.

[image]

The moderator can tick any number of checkboxes and then click "Delete selected". This will prompt for a final confirmation indicating the total number of answers that will be deleted, then it will automatically cast delete votes on each of the selected posts.

### Known limitations

- The script doesn't currently allow to bulk-undelete.
- The script doesn't check if a post is locked.

### Installation

- **[Click to install](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blackgreen100/SO-bookend-helper/master/script.user.js)**
- [source](https://github.com/blackgreen100/SO-bookend-helper/blob/master/script.user.js)

### Bugs, requests

You can post bugs or requests [in the script repo](https://github.com/blackgreen100/SO-bookend-helper/issues).